# Open source non-browser clients for Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, client

Are there any open source clients for Stack Exchange sites that do not run in the browser?  Almost all Stack Exchange sites appear as only text to me.

It appears this happens whenever I temporarily *deactivate* *HTTPS Everywhere* on a Stack Exchange site.  It appears that deleting cookies from that site does not resolve the problem, so I'm just stuck abandoning that site, although sometimes they start working again for some unknown reason.

Comment: Did you search at http://stackapps.com?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but might help you solve your problem.... the CSS and other static images/content is served by a CDN (cdn.sstatic.net) and when it is missing, it has a text-only appearance.  You could be having trouble reaching the CDN so might be worth exploring why.  Is HTTPS Everywhere or another add-in causing a problem?  Or is it something outside of browser?

Comment: I'm running a FireFox behind Tor, but not Tor Browser itself.  I want a work profile with cookies for work related sites, like SE.  It's potentially related to the exit node that Tor is using for cdn.sstatic.net.  I could try pinning the exit nodes for SE sites to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's Emacs with [Sean Allred's `sx` package](https://stackapps.com/questions/3950/sx-stack-exchange-for-emacs).

```
M-x install-package RET
M-x sx-tab-all-questions RET
stacko RET
```

It doesn't have all the site features, not even as much as the mobile apps, but it is enough to browse the site, post questions, answers and comments, vote, and edit.

Comment: Ain't fond of Emacs myself, but Emacs is preferable to SE's janky browser app.